Microphone PS3 Eye does not work
I am using ubuntu for a few hours but i can't figure it out why i can't find on screen my microphone if it's plugged in.
The microphone is not working and not even displayed in my settings

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
